# collectionView divided into three lines swift 4

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, uicollectionview

I need to create a collectionView to display a series of images, individually for each photo. I'm trying to reproduce what you see in the picture, view a photo and then scroll left or right for the next. I can not create the layout of the `collectionView`

[image: example image]

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return self.datasource.count
}

//UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout - constraint della collecion view da innestare
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
    let width = (UIScreen.main.bounds.size.width - 3) / 3
    let height = width
    return CGSize(width: width, height: height)
}
```

Comment: if you want the cell to occupy the entire width of the screen then don't divide by 3. `let width = (UIScreen.main.bounds.size.width)`. Also, it's better not to use the screen size. If it is a `ViewController` use `let width = self.view.frame.width` or if it is a `UIView` that is presenting the collectionView use `let width = self.frame.width`. Also make sure you make the layout horizontal. `layout.scrollDirection = .horizontal`

Comment: Perhaps give the cell the whole size of the view controller. Then in the cell add a constraint for image view i.e center the image view and give its total height of the the cell * 0.3. also pin its left right edges. Or you can give the mentioned constraint to you collectionview if you dont want the cross to scroll.

Answer (score 0):

swift 4:

```
  func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {

     //calculation of cell size
    return CGSize(width: self.collectionview.frame.size.width,height: 180)
      }

  func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, insetForSectionAt section: Int) -> UIEdgeInsets {
    // indentation 
    return UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 23, 20, 20)
    }
```

If you want to drag to horizontal or vertical, in collectionview there is a "scroll Direction" attribute. You can change it to horizontal or vertical.

Comment: why would you divide by 2? Full width is needed here